# Show that $|\langle Tv, v\rangle\le \|Tv\|$ with equality iff v is an eigenvector of $T$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $v\in V$ with $\|v\|=1$. Show that $$|\langle Tv, v\rangle\le \|Tv\|$$
with equality iff v is an eigenvector of $T$.

---

I can show that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then we have $Tv=\lambda v$. Then
$$
|\langle Tv, v\rangle=|\lambda|= \|Tv\|
$$

But how to show the inverse?

Comment: 3 questions in half an hour... take time to breath... and take time to really work on your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we'd have $|\langle Tv,v\rangle|\le ||Tv||.||v||$.

Equality in Cauchy-Schwarz occurs when the vectors are parallel.